# Unable to target a parent of specific element with id

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on this demo code. Why am I not able to target a parent of specific element with id? I want to add `active` class to parent of a `a` element which has an `id` of `#map`

```js
$("#map .nav-tabs>li>a").parent().addClass('active');
$("#map .nav-tabs li>a").parent().addClass('active');
```

```css
.active {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="nav-tabs">
  <li><a id="map"> Map</a></li>
  <li><a id="tap"> Tap</a></li>
  <li><a id="app"> App</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: map is not a parent of anything.  it is a child of nav-tabs.  `$('#map').parent()` should work fine to target the li around the link.

Comment: `$("#map").parent().addClass('active');`
This will add active class on li

Comment: try like this $(".nav-tabs>li>a#map").parent().addClass('active');

Comment: @MohsinMehmood if you use `a#map` jQuery has to resort to using querySelector() or querySelectorAll(), or using Sizzle, where as if you just use `#map` it can use getElementById() .  An id must be unique so it should be safe to just use it as is and reap the (un-noticable but present) performance benefits

Comment: @Taplar! Thanks and I have updated my comment

Answer (score 2):

You can use `.closest()` instead of *.parent()* for more future-proof flexibility

```js
$(".nav-tabs>li>a").closest("#map, #app").addClass('active');
```

```css
.active {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="nav-tabs">
  <li><a id="map"> Map</a></li>
  <li><a id="tap"> Tap</a></li>
  <li><a id="app"> App</a></li>
</ul>
```

But since IDs are unique, you can target directly your ID

```js
$("#map, #app").addClass('active');
```

```css
.active {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="nav-tabs">
  <li><a id="map"> Map</a></li>
  <li><a id="tap"> Tap</a></li>
  <li><a id="app"> App</a></li>
</ul>
```

Which makes me think you're actually asking an XY question - where your actual need is to target a parent on click or similar:

```js
$(".nav-tabs").on("click", ".nav-tabs-tab", function() {
  $(this).addClass("active");
  // or 
  // $(this).closest("li").addClass("active");
  // or
  // $(this).closest("desiredSelector").addClass("active");
  // you got the point
});
```

```css
.active {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul class="nav-tabs">
  <li><a class="nav-tabs-tab">Map</a></li>
  <li><a class="nav-tabs-tab">Tap</a></li>
  <li><a class="nav-tabs-tab">App</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Very much `closest` over `parent`.

Answer (score 0):

Your selector is flawed. You selector would match the anchor in this html:

```
<div id="map">
  <ul class="nav-tabs">
    <li><a>foo</a>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Just drop the id in the selector:

```
$(".nav-tabs>li>a").parent().addClass('active');
```

If you want to target a specific anchor do this:

```
$("#map").parent().addClass('active');
```